# Using someone else's iTunes account, even when you have your own

Tags: itunes

My husband and I both have iTunes accounts.
Can I sign onto his account to download some of his music.

Comment: Do you have the same account or you have an account on your own?

Comment: You can set up [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060) which would allow you to share apps/music etc

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can listen to any of your family member's music, but not in the way you suggested. In fact, you can even use any of their purchases. To do that you need to have Family Sharing.

Go to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201088 to setup Family Sharing.

Answer (score 0):

In short, **no**. Apple does not let people from different iTunes accounts sync music to the same device. Only devices registered with a specific Apple ID can get iCloud music from that Apple ID. However, if the music is from a CD or non-iTunes store source, it is unsigned and the raw .mp4 files can be transferred from iTunes to iTunes. Simply drag the Album or song or playlist onto a USB Flash drive and add it to your iTunes.